# VC++ compresses my structures?

Tags: visual-c++

When I compile

```
struct s{
 char name[30];
 char phonenumbers[48];
}
```

, set the values to name="hello world" phonenumbers="0000000000", then have my code save it to a file using standard fstream, the output is as follows.

```
.hello......9....b......x%..Ji.00000....6...2^....h...............h.........X.,.U..u......L=.i.u....u....+..s..,.........XY.l......L=..L=f]........h..........Bol$.,...........h.......,...h.+..s
```

How can I make it not compress/cut the data?

Comment: It never compresses or cuts your data, you have a bug somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to override the stream operators and do whatever serialization you would like